# PHP - remove characteres from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["recipients"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["recipient_0"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["phone-number"]=>
      string(12) "068-842-7893"
    },
["recipient_1"]=>
array(1) {
  ["phone-number"]=>
  string(12) "068-842-7893"
},
["recipient_2"]=>
array(1) {
  ["phone-number"]=>
  string(12) "068-842-7893"
}
  }....
}
```

I need to remove all non numeric characters from the phone-number. How can I do this?

Comment: Start with showing us some attempts

Comment: `str_replace('-','',$array['recipients']['recipient_0'][phone-number])` if the structure is always the same

Comment: @treegarden - I forgot to tell that recipients array can have a lot of recipients. Question edited

Comment: Then wrap it in a for loop

Answer (score 2):

See the `preg_replace` function:

```
$number = preg_replace('~[^\d]~', '', $array['recipients']['recipient_0']['phone-number']);
```

For more recipients (based on OP comment below):

```
foreach ($array['recipients'] as $r) {
    echo preg_replace('~[^\d]~', '', $r['phone-number']);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell, the recipients array can have 1 to many recipients. Edited the question.

Comment: @Sasha: so add a foreach loop, no problem.

Comment: @Sasha: if the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Below are incorrect answers too (from Flosculus), so the next readers should see what answer is correct and what is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide your code. This might help you.

This will remove all non-numeric characters from your string.

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
```

According to your code:

```
$number_of_recipients = count($array["recipients"]);
for($i=0; $i<$number_of_recipients; $i++){
    echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $array["recipients"]["recipient_$i"]["phone-number"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
foreach ($arr['recipients'] as & $recipient) {
    $recipient['phone-number'] = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', null, $recipient['phone-number']);
}
```

You can also walk the array, applying a function to each value:

```
array_walk($arr['recipients'], function ( & $value) {
    $value['phone-number'] = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', null, $value['phone-number']);
});
```